# Need to Generate the columns value based on the Previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, cumulative-sum

Please look at this picture, All the required formula has been mentioned below the columns.

for better clarity my request is...

Column Name "E" : Item open in current month + historical open items (Previous months Sum)

Column Name "F" Warehouse : open items - closed items.

Need of SQL query.. Thanks in advance !

[image]

Comment: Feeling Sad No Help !

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at these SQL Server built-in functions.

[LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx)

[LEAD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx)

This post has an example for previous value in SQL Server 2005 and 2012 (this one uses LAG function).
[How to get previous and current row value using recursive CTE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127636/how-to-get-previous-and-current-row-value-using-recursive-cte)

Comment: They don't do running totals and aren't available in 2008.

Comment: Hi @eternal This is not only about previous value. we have some agg function involved and again its not in 2012. Thank you for you participation.